# Problemas al usar los archivos en C#

Tags: c#

Buen dia, soy nuevo en c# y estoy haciendo un programa para la universidad y me piden que haga uso de estructuras y archivos, pero se me presenta un problema cuando quiero imprimir los datos, ya que al momento de leerlos la consola me salta un error y no se porque sucederá eso:  anexo parte de mi código y una captura del error para que se entienda mucho mejor. Cabe mencionar que cuando es un dato el que deseo imprimir y no uso estructuras, me funciona perfectamente. Gracias de antemano [image: Este es el error que se presenta]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace Archivos_Ejemplo3
{
class Program
{
struct Persona
{
public String Nombre;
public int Edad;
public String Direccion;
}
static StreamWriter Escribir;

static StreamReader Leer;
  static void Main(string[] args)

  {

      int i = 0, contador = 0;
      String Opcion, Linea;

      Persona Acceso = new Persona();

      do

      {
          Console.Clear();
          Escribir = new StreamWriter("DatosPersonales.txt", true);
          Console.WriteLine("Persona con ID:[" + (i + 1) + "]");
          Console.WriteLine("Nombre:");
          Acceso.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Edad:");
          Acceso.Edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("Direccion:");
          Acceso.Direccion = Console.ReadLine();
          //Escribimos sobre el archivo
          Escribir.WriteLine("Persona con ID:" + (i + 1));
          Escribir.WriteLine("Nombre: " + Acceso.Nombre);
          Escribir.WriteLine("Edad: " + Acceso.Edad);
          Escribir.WriteLine("Direccion: " + Acceso.Direccion);
          Escribir.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
          i++;
          Escribir.Close();
          Console.WriteLine("Desea ingresar otro registro? (S/N)");
          Opcion = Console.ReadLine();
          if (Opcion == "N" || Opcion == "n")

          {
              Process.Start("DatosPersonales.txt");

          }
      } while (Opcion == "S" || Opcion == "s");

      Leer = new StreamReader("DatosPersonales.txt");
      while ((Linea = Leer.ReadLine()) != null)

      {
          Console.WriteLine(Linea);
          contador++;

      }
      Leer.Close();
      Console.ReadKey();

  }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema subyace en la linea donde tienes(la cual esta bien a nivel de funcion):

```
Process.Start("DatosPersonales.txt");
```

usa mejor esta sintaxis en caso de querer visualizarlo con notepad por ejemplo:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "DatosPersonales.txt");
```

tu codigo como tal no esta mal de hecho deberia ejecutarse por al intentar abrir deberia abrirlo con el programa asociado a txt.